# Docker: get access to wifi interface

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, wifi

I am pretty new to docker. At the moment I want to maintain a network of different Rapsberry PIs. Each PI should have the same OS with exactly the same system running. To handle deployment and updates of Software, I want to handle these things by docker.

Currently I am using HypriotOS, which offers docker on their Images.

My Main goal is to run an applocation in the docker containers, which need to access the wifi interface directly. The pure network access won't be enough, there needs to be deeper access like changing the wifi mode (Monitor Mode).

Long Story short: is it possible to passthrough an USB WiFi card directly to the docker Container, that it appears as wlan0 interface? Or are there other ways that you can think of?

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: --net=host exposes all the interfaces, in other words no network virtualization.

Comment: See this related answer: http://serverfault.com/a/695771/91685

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the `privileged` flag for your container, it will give you full access to the devices on the system. See the [Docker Run Documention](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) for more information.

Comment: You could also use the ``--device`` flag to just add the wifi interface.

Comment: That is true, --device will give you access to just a device or --net=host will work as well.